# * in function args (C)

Tags: c

```
void counter(unsigned * val)
{
    static unsigned count=0;
    *val= ++count;
}
```

Why is there a space between `unsigned` and `val`? Shouldn't it be just `*val` to point to the memory address at `val`?

Comment: The spacing is (in this case) not significant.

Answer (score 6):

The space is irrelevant.

It could be more than one, or newlines or even no space.

```
unsigned
*
val;
unsigned              *           val;
unsigned * val;
unsigned *val; // my preference
unsigned* val;
unsigned*val;
```

Answer (score 3):

> Shouldn't it be just *val to point to the memory address at val?

Not necessary.
You can write it as

```
unsigned * val
unsigned *val  
unsigned* val
```

all are equivalent.
Spaces (newline characters) are removed during [lexical analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) phase of compiler so any number of spaces doesn't matter.

```
 unsigned                 *  val
```

Answer (score 1):

The placement of the space is irrelevant, but *when declaring variables in general*, it can matter for readability:

```
unsigned * val, other_val;
unsigned *val, other_val; 
unsigned* val, other_val;
```

In the first case and especially in the last case other_val can be misunderstood as being a pointer; only the second case that ties the * to the variable makes it obvious that only val is a pointer to an unsigned and that other_val is an unsigned.

*This doesn't apply in the case of function parameters as every parameter needs to have a type declared anyway.*

Comment: True, but the question is about function argument. You can't have a function with parameter `int *a, b`

Comment: @YuHao Oh, right. I read the question a bit too quick and missed that it was in the context of functions; my answer was intended to comment of style in general. I clarified my answer a bit.